# How can i find out why my POST Request went wrong

Tags: reactjs, post, xmlhttprequest

I always get a 400 Error when trying to add my data to a database with a POST Request. Thats my method of adding the data. I also made sure that there is a POST option so it should work but kinda doesn't.

```
const mitgliedAdd = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(mitarbeiter)
    };
    fetch("/api/member", mitgliedAdd);
```

Thats the dataset how it is in the database (an empty example)

```
{"number":"","firstName":"","lastName":"","begin":"","end":null,"email":"","durationStudentSelfGov":0}
```

And here's the data i would like to add

```
{"number":"0148","firstName":"test","lastName":"test","begin":"2022-06-06","end":null,"email":"bla@bla.com","durationStudentSelfGov":5}
```

I really would like to find out why i get a Bad Request Error...

```
class MemberView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Member.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer

class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ("__all__")
```

Comment: The fetch looks good. Please show the code of "member".

Comment: Added the code in the question